# using xsl:for-each inside or outside a xsl:table

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm running into an issue showing *"fo:table-row is missing child elements"*. I know it relates to running the xsl:for-each in the below template. But I need to navigate through all Booleans and report it in a table. How would I go about using for-each within a table? or is that not possible?

```
 <xsl:template match="boolean">
            <fo:table-row>
                <xsl:for-each select='boolean'>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>
                      <xsl:value-of select="$caption" />
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="bml:Value='0'">No</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>Yes</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
```

This is giving me a *"fo:table-row is missing child elements"*. If I remove the for-each it will put the a single boolean value in the correct location in my table I created, I just can't get this to go through all booleans within the output to grab each boolean for the graph. Any ideas on how to iterate and use for-each with a table?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that shows an example of input and the expected output.

Comment: Does your source document contain an element named `boolean` that has another element named `boolean` as a child? If not, your code is wrong, because this template matches a `boolean` element and then navigates to its `boolean` children.

Answer (score 0):

`match="boolean"` says that the context item is a `<boolean>`.  Unless you have `<boolean>` that contains `<boolean>`, the `<xsl:for-each>` will not select anything.

Iterating in XSLT is often not the best approach.  If you remove the `xsl:for-each` and make whatever `xsl:apply-templates` that selected the `boolean` select all of the `boolean`, then the template will be used for every `boolean` and you'll get a bunch of table rows as expected.